# How to enumerates application and driver for Power Requests?

Tags: c#

How to enumerates application and driver for Power Requests?

As example, the program "powercfg.exe" get list of application and driver.

```
powercfg /requests
```

Me need get the information:

> Enumerates application and driver Power Requests. Power Requests
>   prevent the computer from automatically powering off the display or
>   entering a low-power sleep mode.

Comment: You may need to write a filter driver for this (not sure if there is any api), However you could just call `powercfg /requests` and interpret the results